# How can I get user's idle time of whole day?

Tags: users, statistics, hid

How can we get the user's idle time, defined as the time during which the user hasn't struck the keyboard or even made a mouse movement in Ubuntu 22.04. It should display with the username, the user's login, logout time & idle time interval of the user within the whole day.

Can anyone let me know, how can we do that?

I want this idle time of the user so that I get the details of the user who is idle for minutes/hours at that specific day time interval, in a whole day.

Is there any script or command to get the details of the user for the particular date & time at which the user was idle?

Comment: Why do these utilities not work? How do they fail? What kind of resolution do you want? All milliseconds of idleness? All seconds? Minutes? Hours? Please [edit] your question and give us more details.

Comment: Discrete events are instantaneous: you need to deal with the acceptable run-length statistically. I sometimes spend hours not typing or mousing -- it's called "Thinking", or "Mentoring", or several other things of benefit to my client.